# Getting Non Filtered Item from array list using Guava Library

Tags: data-structures, collections, guava

I can get all item according to my filter condition using bellow function, but I need also list of items which is not filtered, I mean to say item whose isGroup is true I can get it easily but no way to get items whose isGroup is true, I dont want to use another filter for the same task, is there any build in function for this ?

```
  final Collection nonGroupItems= Collections2.filter(rosterList, new Predicate<Roster>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Roster input) {
                return  ! input.getIsGroup();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`Multimaps.index(Iterable, Function)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) to index/group/partition your values by some key (in this case by `isGroup`). You'll then have access to each list of values: one list for values whose `isGroup` returns `true` and another list for values whose `isGroup` returns `false`.

e.g.:

```java
final ImmutableListMultimap<Boolean, Roster> rostersByIsGroup = Multimaps.index(rosterList,
        new Function<Roster, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(Roster input) {
                return input.getIsGroup();
            }
        });
final ImmutableList<Roster> groupItems = rostersByIsGroup.get(true);
final ImmutableList<Roster> nonGroupItems = rostersByIsGroup.get(false);
```

And if your using Java 8:

```java
final ImmutableListMultimap<Boolean, Roster> rostersByIsGroup = Multimaps.index(rosterList,
        Roster::getIsGroup);
final ImmutableList<Roster> groupItems = rostersByIsGroup.get(true);
final ImmutableList<Roster> nonGroupItems = rostersByIsGroup.get(false);
```